Existence of Permutation for Summation of Polynomial Terms Involving N-th Roots of Unity
Let ( f(x) ) be a complex polynomial of degree less than  n , and let  N  be a positive integer s.t.  $N = m_1 m_2 \cdots m_n $, where $ m_1, m_2, \cdots, m_n $ are pairwise coprime positive integers greater than 1. Let $ \omega $ be a primitive  N-th root of unity.Then try to prove that there exists a permutation $ \{i_k\}_{k=0}^{N-1} $ of $ \{0, 1, \dots, N-1\} $ s.t.$\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} f(i_k) \omega^k = 0.$
This is the final exercise of polynomial theory in my linear algebra book and I have been thinking for over one day.
What I have tried are as follows:
All powers of $\omega$ can be reduced to $\omega_1^{r_1}\omega_2^{r_2}\cdots\omega_n^{r_n}$ where $r_i<m_i$ and $\omega_i$ is $m_i$-th root of unity.
Then we express $i_k$ by $r_1+r_2m_1+r_3m_1m_2+\cdots+r_nm_1m_2\cdots m_{n-1}$
Therefore we need to prove $\sum\limits_{r_i<m_i}f(r_1,r_2,\cdots,r_n)\omega_1^{r_1}\omega_2^{r_2}\cdots\omega_n^{r_n}=0$
If I expand the expresion,that seems to be more complex.And I don't know how to use the condition of deg(f)<n.At this point, I can no longer find the mathematical tools to proceed.

What if $f(x)=x$ and $N=3$? You want $\rho+2\rho'=0$ for some pair of cube roots of unity $\rho$ and $\rho'$, which certainly doesn't happen.

@GerryMyerson If $N=3$ then isn't $n=1$ so $f(x)=x$ isn't allowed. You'll still get a contradiction to the question as posed, but isn't there a typo and the sums should start at $k=0$?

@anc, thanks, I missed the spot where $n$ was defined. Should be easy enough to fix. The sum does start at $k=0$; the $i_k$ are a permutation of ${0,1,2}$, and $f(0)=0$.

@ancientmathematician Sorry for my mistake and I've edited now correctly.

By linearity it is enough to consider the problem for $p(z) = z^n$, and it is easy to see that the result holds for $n = 0$. I tried brute forcing some examples, but only had some success for very small ones (like $N = 2 \cdot 3$, $N = 2 \cdot 5$ and $N = 3 \cdot 4$ and $n = 1$), where there appear to be are several solutions in each case. The script I used to calculate these is here if it helps: https://gist.github.com/gunnihinn/769178db178fb3a7942ead0510464e64

@GunnarÞórMagnússon Does that mean that the exercise is wrong？

Maybe I've approached it but I'm but sure.
Obviously， $\omega^k\in\{\omega_1^{r_1}\omega_2^{r_2}\cdots\omega_n^{r_n}|r_i<m_i\}$, $\omega_i$ is $m_i$-th root of unity.
We construct an unordered sequence$\{r_1+r_2m_1+r_3m_1m_2+\cdots+r_nm_1m_2\cdots m_{n-1}\},r_i<m_i$(Mixed radix).
We claim that：$\sum\limits_{0\leqslant r_i<m_i}f(r_1,r_2,\cdots,r_n)\omega_1^{r_1}\omega_2^{r_2}\cdots\omega_n^{r_n}=0$
We just need to prove that$\forall k<n,\sum\limits_{r_i<m_i}(r_1+r_2m_1+r_3m_1m_2+\cdots+r_nm_1m_2\cdots m_{n-1})^k\omega_1^{r_1}\omega_2^{r_2}\cdots\omega_n^{r_n}=0$
We perform mathematical induction on n:
When $n=1$,LHS=$\sum\limits_{r_i<m_i}\omega_1^{r_1}\omega_2^{r_2}\cdots\omega_n^{r_n}=\sum\limits_{r_1<m_1}\omega_1^{r_1}(\cdots)=0$
If that suits the case of n-1,consider n.Let $R=r_1+r_2m_1+r_3m_1m_2+\cdots+r_{n-1}m_1m_2\cdots m_{n-2}$
\begin{align*}LHS&=\sum\limits_{r_i<m_i}\sum\limits_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}r_n^jm_1^jm_2^j\cdots m_{n-1}^jR^{k-j}\omega_1^{r_1}\omega_2^{r_2}\cdots\omega_n^{r_n}\\
  &=\sum\limits_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}m_1^jm_2^j\cdots m_{n-1}^j(\sum\limits_{r_n<m_n}r_n^j\omega_n^{r_n})(\sum\limits_{r_i<m_i,i\neq m}R^{k-j}\omega_1^{r_1}\omega_2^{r_2}\cdots\omega_{n-1}^{r_{n-1}})\\&=(\sum\limits_{r_n<m_n}\omega_n^{r_n})(\sum\limits_{r_i<m_i,i\neq m}R^{k}\omega_1^{r_1}\omega_2^{r_2}\cdots\omega_{n-1}^{r_{n-1}})\text{(we can't promise when j=0)}\\&=0
 \end{align*}
And that's all for my approval.Can anyone check it for me pls.
